# How to start mysql on the Xampp Control Panel?

Tags: mysql

I have been working on phpmyadmin for the past couple of days. Everything was working perfectly fine until I saw this problem which was not there yesterday.

```
4:19:45 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
4:19:45 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:19:45 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:19:45 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:19:45 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:19:45 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
4:19:45 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

What I don't understand is that the problem was not there all these days, so I really do not know what is wrong.

I tried deleting `ibdata1` folder from my `xampp/mysql/data` directory, but every time I start mysql on the xampp control panel, it reappears again and again.

Can someone please give me a proper solution? I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you do this? "Press the Logs button to view error logs"

Comment: @ceejayoz, i did. but im not sure what i should do over there.

Comment: You should look for log entries from MySQL. Chances are there'll be something there indicating the reason for the failure.

Comment: ibdata1 is the data file of innodb (if you are not enabled directory per db option...), you should never delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Check programs that are running on same port, with `netstat` command.
Also check you xampp mysql log file.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the port in the my.ini to something other than the default (3306) and start it up again, if this works, you have another service listening on port 3306.

Then you can find out which with `netstat`. you can find the process, shut it down, restart mysql with the default port in xammp.

If it doesn't work, there is something wrong with your installation. going through the logs for errors will help troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved my issue by trying the following operation for different hardware and software configuration :

`**NOTE: Every step includes closing and starting of XAMPP after performing each step.**`

1. If you're having any **SQL** related software, then uninstall that software.
2. Some higher version may not support try installing 5.x instead of 7.x
3. Try starting the application with Admin Permission by right click on application => **Run as administrator**